# Failed to Create Assembly (SQL Server) to excute an C# program that reference NetFwTypeLib

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to create an Assembly in my database in order to excute an program that I make when the trigger is fired.
My Assembly requires the assemblies of System.Windows.Form and Interop.NetFwTypeLib to create, I added them all to my database successfully
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1qMN.png)
However the system still show me this error

> Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Assembly 'FwSetting' references assembly 'interop.netfwtypelib, version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

You can see that the version of Interop.NetFwTypeLib that I added in the database totally match with what the error required, that make me very confused.

From my understanding of that message, all I tried is to find an older firewallapi.dll version in hope that would have an older Interop.NetFwTypeLib.dll version, but it doesn't apparently.
Here is the sql code to create the assemblies

```
sp_configure 'clr enable', 1  
RECONFIGURE
ALTER DATABASE gdt SET TRUSTWORTHY ON

use gdt 
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Interop.NetFwTypeLib] 
AUTHORIZATION dbo
FROM FROM "C:\Path\That\Go\To\My\Project\FwSetting\FwSetting\bin\Debug\Interop.NetFwTypeLib.dll"
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe 

CREATE ASSEMBLY WindowsForm 
AUTHORIZATION dbo 
FROM "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll"
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe 

CREATE ASSEMBLY FwSetting
AUTHORIZATION dbo 
FROM "C:\Path\That\Go\To\My\Project\FwSetting\FwSetting\bin\Debug\FwSetting.exe"
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe
```

For more information, I'm using .NET Framework 2.0 for this program, the database is SQL Server 2005 and I've read [this document](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server-2005) to learn how to create an assembly.
Any idea of what my problem is?

Comment: The framework and SQL server are out of date for years now, why not start with Vs 2022 und SQL Server 2022

Comment: Also... `System.Windows.Forms`? SQL Server is a headless environment, why are you trying to use GUI assemblies in it?

Comment: Create assemblies just to run some program sounds a bit weird. You can use xp_cmdshell, OR even better, start a agent job which executes your program. Or just create assembly that executes programs, you don't need any dependancies on weird stuff for that

Comment: Could you tell us what this program you're starting supposed to be doing? This might be a bad idea if your program uses a GUI

Comment: @siggemannen I used xp_cmdshell and solved the problem, it's a simple application that make some changes in a inbound rule, it will close automatically when the task is done. I'll keep it at a GUI app anyway for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better way using `xp_cmdshell`

```
CREATE TRIGGER Fwtrg ON mdt for Insert
AS 
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell '"C:\Path\That\Go\To\My\Project\FwSetting\FwSetting\bin\Debug\FwSetting.exe"'
GO
```

Refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3179a629-d97e-43a3-b01b-929ad611712a/trigger-to-run-an-exe-file?forum=aspdatasourcecontrols)

Comment: You're better off creating a SQL Server Agent job in Powershell that runs the application, then use `sp_startjob`. And running this in a trigger is possibly the most horrible thing I've ever seen: the insert will have to wait until the application closes.

Comment: @Charlieface I know, but considering that insert won't be performed frequently, I think it's alright